# Running `python -m unittest` changes the way exceptions with overriden `__name__` are printed in the traceback

Tags: python, exception, factory, python-unittest

I have a piece of code that dynamically creates `Exception`s. Every exception class created in this way gets its `__name__` overwritten:

```py
def exception_injector(name, parent, module_dict):
    class product_exception(parent):
        pass
    product_exception.__name__ = name
    product_exception.__module__ = module_dict["__name__"]
    module_dict[name] = product_exception
```

When I use it regularly it prints everything out just fine:

```
>>> namespace = {"__name__": "some.module"}
>>> exception_injector("TestError", Exception, namespace)
>>> raise namespace["TestError"]("What's going on?")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
some.module.TestError: What's going on?
```

But when I use the `unittest` module  the original `__name__` is printed:

```
>>> import unittest
>>> class DemoTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
...     def test_raise(self):
...         namespace = {"__name__": "some.module"}
...         exception_injector("TestError", Exception, namespace)
...         namespace["TestError"]("What's going on?")
...
>>> unittest.main(defaultTest="DemoTestCase", argv=["demo"], exit=False)
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_raise (__main__.DemoTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in test_raise
some.module.exception_injector.<locals>.product_exception: What's going on?

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
<unittest.main.TestProgram object at 0x1017c3eb8>
```

From where on the exception object could the `unittest` module be getting this original information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unittests use the [`traceback` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) to format exceptions. You can reproduce your output by doing the same:

```
>>> import traceback
>>> try:
...     raise namespace["TestError"]("What's going on?")
... except Exception as e:
...     tb = traceback.TracebackException.from_exception(e)
...     print(*tb.format())
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
 some.module.exception_injector.<locals>.product_exception: What's going on?
```

What is being printed is the object `__module__` attribute value<sup>*</sup>, with [`object.__qualname__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__qualname__) appended (with a dot separator), rather than `__module__` plus `__name__`:

```
>>> namespace["TestError"].__qualname__
'exception_injector.<locals>.product_exception'
```

The qualified name includes the [full scope where the class was created](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name) (function names here, but this could also include class names).

If your aim is to add exceptions to the global namespaces of a module, you can just set it to the same value as `name`:

```
>>> namespace["TestError"].__qualname__ = "TestError"
>>> try:
...     raise namespace["TestError"]("What's going on?")
... except Exception as e:
...     tb = traceback.TracebackException.from_exception(e)
...     print(*tb.format())
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
 some.module.TestError: What's going on?
```

or in the context of your code:

```
def exception_injector(name, parent, module_dict):
    class product_exception(parent, details=args):
        pass

    product_exception.__name__ = name
    product_exception.__qualname__ = name
    product_exception.__module__ = module_dict["__name__"]
    module_dict[name] = product_exception
```

---

<sup>*</sup> The traceback module omits the exception module if the module name is either `__main__` or `builtins`.

Comment: Which now that you say it makes sense, I've never seen a builtins.AttributeError :)